# Why is setting process group (setpgrp) allowed in a docker container but not in a kubernetes pod

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

If I run the following in a docker container (with python of course)

```
python -c 'import os; os.setpgrp()'
```

It executes just fine, but if I run it as a kubernetes job in the same container, it will return:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Is there something about the process model of kubernetes compared to a standalone docker container that prevents processes in a container from setting their process group id? I can't seem to find any documentation or references to this.

Comment: Can you confirm what the uid is when running the command?

Comment: Could you add job yaml and how you run this code in a docker container please